# Error parsing JSON data in java

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have searched for solutions for a day and cannot find one that applies for my situation. I am sorry but I am new to JSON (self taught programmer) and I don't know what classes should I only post, so I will put in everything I have. I am getting the following error from LogCat:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is my class:

```
package com.example.mytravelbuddy;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Itinerary extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //JSON Parser
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    //URL To Get Products
    public static String url = "URL REMOVED"; //Removed my url since i was hosting online

    //JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_ITEMS = "items";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
    private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "Location";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "Latitude";
    private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "Longitude";
    private static final String TAG_TIME = "Time";

    //Array list
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList;

    //Items JSONArray
    JSONArray items = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

        itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new LoadAllItems().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class LoadAllItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Itinerary.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading items. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            //Building Params
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();        

            //Getting JSON String
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);

            try{
                //Getting array of items
                Log.i("Error","ERROR 1"); //This error message is displayed
                items = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEMS); //This is the line that is giving me a problem
                Log.i("Error","ERROR 2"); //This error message is not displayed

                //Looping through
                for(int i = 0; i < items.length();i++){

                    JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Storing JSON item in variable
                    String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    String longitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);
                    String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                    String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);


                    //Creating HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    //Put value in hashmap map
                    map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    map.put(TAG_LONGITUDE, longitude);
                    map.put(TAG_LATITUDE, latitude);
                    map.put(TAG_TIME, time);

                    itemList.add(map);
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }}
}
```

I found in which line I am getting the error by displaying error messages in LogCat.

Here is my PHP file that I am trying to get response from:

```
 <?php

$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "travel_buddy";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database);


get_details();


function get_details(){
$response = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM adventure");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    $response["items"] = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $info = array();
        $info["ID"] = $row["ID"];
        $info["Location"] = $row["Location"];
        $info["Description"] = $row["Description"];
        $info["Latitude"] = $row["Latitude"];
        $info["Longitude"] = $row["Longitude"];
        $info["Time"] = $row["Time"];

        array_push($response["items"], $info);
    }
        $response["success"] = 1;

        echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Information Found";

    echo json_encode($response);
}

}

?>
```

Here is my JSON Response:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "Location": "TEST",
            "Description": "TEST DESC",
            "Latitude": "1",
            "Longitude": "2",
            "Time": "3:00"
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "Location": "TEST2",
            "Description": "TEST2 DESC",
            "Latitude": "1",
            "Longitude": "1",
            "Time": "7:00"
        },
        {
            "ID": "3",
            "Location": "TEST3",
            "Description": "TEST3 DESC",
            "Latitude": "3",
            "Longitude": "4",
            "Time": "12:00"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

Here is my JSON Parser Class:

```
package com.example.mytravelbuddy;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Any help would be really helpful, possible explaining why I have this error so I don't repeat it again.

EDIT: Why is my program getting an XML value?

```
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): <html lang="en" xml:lang="en">
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): <head>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <title>WAMPSERVER Homepage</title>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="txt/html; charset=utf-8" />
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <style type="text/css">
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): * {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin: 0;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  padding: 0;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): html {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  background: #ddd;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): body {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin: 1em 10%;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  padding: 1em 3em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  font: 80%/1.4 tahoma, arial, helvetica, lucida sans, sans-serif;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  border: 1px solid #999;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  background: #eee;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  position: relative;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): #head {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin-bottom: 1.8em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin-top: 1.8em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  padding-bottom: 0em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  letter-spacing: -500em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  text-indent: -500em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  height: 125px;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  background: url(index.php?img=gifLogo) 0 0 no-repeat;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): .utility {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  position: absolute;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  right: 4em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  top: 145px;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  font-size: 0.85em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): .utility li {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  display: inline;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): h2 {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin: 0.8em 0 0 0;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): ul {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  list-style: none;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin: 0;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  padding: 0;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): #head ul li, dl ul li, #foot li {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  list-style: none;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  display: inline;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin: 0;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  padding: 0 0.2em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): ul.aliases, ul.projects, ul.tools {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  list-style: none;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  line-height: 24px;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): ul.aliases a, ul.projects a, ul.tools a {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  padding-left: 22px;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  background: url(index.php?img=pngFolder) 0 100% no-repeat;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): ul.tools a {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  background: url(index.php?img=pngWrench) 0 100% no-repeat;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): ul.aliases a {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  background: url(index.php?img=pngFolderGo) 0 100% no-repeat;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): dl {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin: 0;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  padding: 0;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): dt {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  font-weight: bold;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  text-align: right;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  width: 11em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  clear: both;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): dd {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin: -1.35em 0 0 12em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  padding-bottom: 0.4em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  overflow: auto;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): dd ul li {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  float: left;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  display: block;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  width: 16.5%;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin: 0;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  background: url(index.php?img=pngPlugin) 2px 50% no-repeat;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  line-height: 1.6;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): a {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  color: #024378;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  font-weight: bold;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  text-decoration: none;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): a:hover {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  color: #04569A;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  text-decoration: underline;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): #foot {
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  text-align: center;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  margin-top: 1.8em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  border-top: 1px solid #999;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  padding-top: 1em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  font-size: 0.85em;
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): }
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): </style>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):     
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="index.php?img=favicon" type="image/ico" />
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): </head>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): <body>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <div id="head">
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <h1><abbr title="Windows">W</abbr><abbr title="Apache">A</abbr><abbr title="MySQL">M</abbr><abbr title="PHP">P</abbr></h1>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <ul>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):          <li>PHP 5</li>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):          <li>Apache 2</li>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):          <li>MySQL 5</li>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      </ul>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  </div>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <ul class="utility">
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <li>Version 2.4
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589): </li>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <li><a href="?lang=fr">Version Fran&ccedil;aise</a></li>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  </ul>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <h2> Server Configuration </h2>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <dl class="content">
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <dt>Apache Version :</dt>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <dd>2.4.4
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  &nbsp;</dd>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <dt>PHP Version :</dt>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <dd>5.4.16
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  &nbsp;</dd>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <dt>Loaded Extensions : </dt> 
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <dd>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):          <ul>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):          <li>Core</li><li>bcmath</li><li>calendar</li><li>ctype</li><li>date</li><li>ereg</li><li>filter</li><li>ftp</li><li>hash</li><li>iconv</li><li>json</li><li>mcrypt</li><li>SPL</li><li>odbc</li><li>pcre</li><li>Reflection</li><li>session</li><li>standard</li><li>mysqlnd</li><li>tokenizer</li><li>zip</li><li>zlib</li><li>libxml</li><li>dom</li><li>PDO</li><li>Phar</li><li>SimpleXML</li><li>wddx</li><li>xml</li><li>xmlreader</li><li>xmlwriter</li><li>apache2handler</li><li>gd</li><li>mbstring</li><li>mysql</li><li>mysqli</li><li>pdo_mysql</li><li>pdo_sqlite</li><li>mhash</li><li>xdebug</li>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):          </ul>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      </dd>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <dt>MySQL Version :</dt>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <dd>5.6.12
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  &nbsp;</dd>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  </dl>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <h2>Tools</h2>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <ul class="tools">
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <li><a href="?phpinfo=1">phpinfo()</a></li>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <li><a href="phpmyadmin/">phpmyadmin</a></li>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  </ul>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <h2>Your Projects</h2>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <ul class="projects">
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <li><a href="connect_to_db">connect_to_db</a></li><li><a href="phpMyAdmin">phpMyAdmin</a></li><li><a href="travel_buddy">travel_buddy</a></li>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  </ul>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <h2>Your Aliases</h2>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <ul class="aliases">
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <li><a href="phpmyadmin/">phpmyadmin</a></li><li><a href="sqlbuddy/">sqlbuddy</a></li><li><a href="webgrind/">webgrind</a></li>         
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  </ul>
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):  <ul id="foot">
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <li><a href="http://www.wampserver.com">WampServer</a></li> - 
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):         <li><a href="http://www.wampserver.com/en/donations.php">Donate</a></li> -
12-10 15:17:42.975: I/sb.toString()(2589):      <li><a href="http:
```

Comment: When you take the URL from your AsyncTask and put it in the browser, do you get a JSON response?

Comment: @Jon Yes it does work. I removed it because I am hosting it on an online server.

Comment: @DoubleDouble how do i put it all in one string from the php script?

Comment: @user2904544 Sorry, I was mistaken and deleted comment

Comment: @DoubleDouble It's okay. Do you have an idea of what is going on??? I don't know why it's reading it as an xml value!

Comment: @user2904544 Can you provide what your JSON string looks like in the constructor of JSONObject?

Comment: try printing json = sb.toString(); in your debug log and paste it here that way we can see what is returned by your http request.

Comment: Do you need to set an HTTP Accept header with application/json to indicate to the PHP server that you can handle JSON?

Comment: @saiful103a Posted it.

Comment: am not sure if this might be a problem or not but you are passing params in your get request where params is just a blank arraylist do u get the same response with or without parameter in your get request?

Comment: i mean when you test your url in browser

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String url = "URL REMOVED";
```

If you remove the URL then you will be hitting the localhost, thats why your are not seeing the JSON data but the Wamp php info instead.

You mentionned that your are now hosting the script, then you must use that URL:

```
public static String url = "http://www.pathtoyournewscript.com/json.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you with your specifics but if you are looking to use a higher level library you might consider

[Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) it's pretty fast and clean

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it out. Unfortunately time is against me to change my library now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're looking for the json in the right place? I usually use HttpClient and get an HttpResponse object back from a connection like this.

The json is going to be in the response body I believe.

Here's a quick example

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html

And another one

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java